# returning to the JWindow after closing the JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane, jwindow

I display a MessageDialog when the user wants to delete an item or close the window.
when I display the Dialog as follows:

```
else if (e.getSource() == delete_btn)
{
  int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(AgentFrame.this,
     "Are you sure you want to delete Agent: " + availableAgents_list.getSelectedValue().toString() +
     " ?", null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
  {
    availableAgents_list.removeSelectionInterval(availableAgents_list.getSelectedIndex(),
                                                     availableAgents_list.getSelectedIndex());
  }
}
```

When the user presses on YES or CANCEL the window disposes.. and I need to return back to the window to do some actions.

Comment: AgentFrame is my JWindow

Comment: this if statement is in the action performed function. and according to it's action i want to delete the selected item in the JList but before i do i want to ask the user first to confirm on the process of deletion...

Comment: is it so difficult to answer ?!!